# Angular component is called again as a window is resized

Tags: angular, components, breakpoints, reload

I have been noticing that a component's on init is being called as many times as a window is resized. I have a component that calls an API once it is loaded. Once the data is retrieved and the html is rendered with the data it looks ok, but if you resize the window and reach say tablet or mobile breakpoints, the API is called again and you see the loading screen again.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? have searched but haven't found anything related to this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```js
@Component
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  allChildComponentsEmpty = false;
  scheduleItem!: any;
  isLoader: boolean=false;
  public breakpoints = Breakpoints;
  public layoutSize: string | undefined = '';
  handsetView = false;
  tabletView = false;
  widescreenView = false;
  primaryBtn = ButtonColor.primary;
  icon = 'di di-leftArrow';
  isSaved = false;
  isPersonalMeeting: boolean = false;
  isHybridMeeting: boolean = false;
  isWorkMeeting: boolean = false;


  constructor(
    public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private breakpointService: BreakpointService,
    private scheduleService: ScheduleService,
  ) {
    this.breakpointService.startBreakpointSubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllSchedules();
    this.subscribeBreakpoint();
    this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset,
      Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape,
      Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait,
      Breakpoints.Tablet,
      Breakpoints.TabletLandscape,
      Breakpoints.TabletPortrait,
      '(min-width: 1600px)'])
      .subscribe(result => {

        this.handsetView = false;
        this.widescreenView = false;
        const breakpoints = result.breakpoints;

        if (breakpoints[Breakpoints.Tablet] || breakpoints[Breakpoints.TabletLandscape]
          || breakpoints[Breakpoints.TabletPortrait]) {
          this.tabletView = true;
        } else if (breakpoints[Breakpoints.Handset] || breakpoints[Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape]
          || breakpoints[Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait]) {
          this.handsetView = true;
        } else if (this.breakpointObserver.isMatched('(min-width: 1600px)')) {
          this.widescreenView = true;
        }
      });
  }

  private subscribeBreakpoint() {
    this.breakpointService.currentBreakpoint$.pipe(
      tap((breakpoints: string | undefined) => {
        this.layoutSize = breakpoints;
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  checkAllChildComponentsEmpty(): void {
    this.getHybridMeetings();
    this.getPersonalMeetings();
    this.getWorkMeetings();

    this.allChildComponentsEmpty =
      !this.isHybridSchedule && !this.isWorkSchedule && !this.isPersonalSchedule;
  }

  private getHybridSchedule() {
//code to get schedule
  }

  private getPersonalMeetings() {
//code to get schedule
  }

  private getWorkMeetingsSchedule() {
//code to get schedule
  }


  getAllSchedules = () => {
    this.isLoader = true;
    this.scheduleService.getSchedules()
      .subscribe((schedules: Schedules[]) => {
        this.isLoader = false;
        this.scheduleItem = schedule;
              
        if (this.scheduleItem[0].workMeeting && this.scheduleItem[0].workMeeting.length !== 0) {
          this.scheduleItem[0].workMeeting = this.meetingLength(this.scheduleItem[0].workMeeting);
        }
         this.checkAllChildComponentsEmpty();
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have somewhere a `@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])` ?

Comment: I have also seen this and been wondering for myself. Let you know if I find anything.

Comment: No, there is no @HostListener for window resize. It just happens by itself. And thanks, any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you use a javascript library to show the table that need "recalculate" positions. It's this library that makes the "reinit". Please edit your question adding if you're using a library or not. NOTE: futhemore hostListener, you can listen a screen resize using `fromEvent(document,'resize')` or `addEventListener("resize")` or `window.onResize`

Comment: edited the question to add the code snippet, only thing I have is a breakpoint subscriber, but that shouldn't reload the component when tablet breakpoints are hit